# How to fix "Not authorized" error on using "dependency:get" plugin in maven

Tags: maven, maven-plugin

The maven throws out a "Not authorized" error when I using "dependency:get" plugin on the command line. How can I fix it?

I have tried to add my server repository in the .m2/settings.xml.My user name and password are correct. I tried using the same artifact and repository can be downloaded by pom.xml in the IntelliJ.

This is my maven command line, It faild:

```
mvn org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-dependency-plugin:3.1.1:get \
-Dartifact=mygroup:myartifact:myversion:aar \
-DremoteRepositories=public::default::my.repository
```

.m2/setting.xml

```xml
  <servers>
    <server>
      <id>public</id>
      <username>myuser</username>
      <password>mypassword</password>
    </server>
  </servers>
```

.m2/plugin-registry.xml

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<pluginRegistry xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/PLUGIN_REGISTRY/1.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/plugin-registry-1.0.0.xsd"
xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/PLUGIN_REGISTRY/1.0.0"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <plugins>
    <plugin>
      <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
      <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
      <useVersion>3.1.1</useVersion>
      <rejectedVersions/>
    </plugin>
 </plugins>
</pluginRegistry>
```

My pom.xml, It succeeds:

```xml
<dependency>
        <groupId>mygroup</groupId>
        <artifactId>myartifact</artifactId>
        <version>myversion</version>
        <type>aar</type>
</dependency>

<repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>public</id>
            <name>Public Repositories</name>
            <layout>default</layout>
            <url>my.repository</url>
        </repository>
</repositories>
```

Comment: Why are you using `mvn dependency:get` on command line? to get a version you simply add it to the pom file?

Comment: @khmarbaise I want to download remote repository's artifacts to my own repository by gradle. Too many transitional dependencies didn't declare type in gradle. So it will download failed by pom.xml.

Comment: At last, I have solved the problem.O(∩_∩)O~~